# Check a website is build with wordpress or not in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress

What is the simple and best way to check a website is bulid with wordpress or not from its url, in rails?

Comment: why do you need to do that ?

Comment: Its my project related requirement

Comment: you cant check directly using url alone

Comment: @ManeeshaCd. you can check in page source. Maximum projects  has `wp-content`. Or you can use this link https://www.wappalyzer.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there are better approach but you can do this

```
uri = URI.parse("your-url")
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)

response.body.scan('wp-content').present?
```

The idea is almost all wp pages will have generated asset links with `wp-content` in them so I'm just checking that